# Replace substring every >n characters (conditionally insert linebreaks for spaces)

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I would like to replace spaces with linebreaks (`\n`) in a pretty long chracter vector in R. However, I don't want to replace *every* space, but only if the substring exeeds a certain number of characters (`n`).

*Example:*

```
mystring <- "this string is annoyingly long and therefore I would like to insert linebreaks"
```

Now I want to insert linebreaks in `mystring` at every space on the condition that each substring has a length greater than 20 characters (`nchar > 20`).

Hence, the resulting string is supposed to look like this:

```
"this string is annoyingly\nlong and therefore I would\nlike to insert linebreaks")
```

Linebreaks (`\n`) were inserted after 25, 26 and 25 characters.

How can I achieve this? 
Maybe something combining `gsub` and `strsplit`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may use `.{21,}?\s` regex to match any 21 (since `nchar > 20`) chars or more, but as few as possible, up to the nearest whitespace:

```
> gsub("(.{21,}?)\\s", "\\1\n", mystring)
[1] "this string is annoyingly\nlong and therefore I would\nlike to insert linebreaks"
```

**Details**:

- `(.{21,}?)` - Group 1 capturing any 21 chars or more, but as few as possible (as `{21,}?` is a *lazy* quantifier)
- `\\s` - a whitespace

The replacement contains the backreference to Group 1 to reinsert the text before the whitespace, and the newline char (feel free to add CR, too, if needed).

Comment: Why are the comma and the question mark needed here? I believe it would work to match 21 characters up to the space eliminating the need for the comma. I don't understand what the question mark is accomplishing.

Comment: @jtr13 It is explained in the answer: *any 21 chars or more, but as few as possible (as {21,}? is a lazy quantifier)*. `{21,}?` matches more than 21, but as few as possible, that is, `.{21,}?` will grab any 21 chars and then any chars up to the first whitespace.

Comment: Right, but what I'm asking is why you need the "or more"... can't you do `.{21}\s` and exactly match the 21 characters immediately before the space?

Comment: @jtr13 You can use `.{21}\s` if it is your intention. OP had a different issue.